# How do I hide text format options in node view with in place editing?

Tags: input-formats

I am using drupal 7 version with in place editing module [editablefields](https://drupal.org/project/editablefields)
I was able to hide the text format options in edit mode with [simplify module](https://drupal.org/project/simplify)  but in node view mode are still there.

Please, do you have any module or custom module with hooks that I could use or do?
!

Answer (score 2):

You can find multiple questions/answers to this problem in this site... One of the most recommeded approach is using `hook_form_alter` hook: example:

```
function MY_MODULE_OR_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // dpm($form);
  // dpm($form_id);

  if($form_id == 'MY_NODE_FORM_ID') {
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'custom_my_node_form_after_build';
  }
}

function custom_my_node_form_after_build($form) {
  // dpm($form);
  // Find the right field's format option with dpm() function

  $form['MY_FIELD']['und']['0']['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: But with hook_form_alter I can modify the edit tab, but I want to hide these options in node_view where a certain field is editable (I am using FULL html, the filtered is disabled)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable text formats from this page admin/config/content/formats

Comment: I want to use Full HTML, the filtered HTML is disabled

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can do this task by various way....

1. See the screenshot of display setting and make it plain.
   [image]
2. Use hook_node_view or  template_preprocess_page or  template_preprocess_node_page and just unset the format key of an array $var.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks but
 I cannot do the first way because in this field I choose the added by this module "editablefields" the field to be editable, so I cannot choose both in this dropdown shown above